# How can I show that for matrix $A$ , $A^t A $ is not equal to $ A A^t $ in general?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transpose

How can I show that for matrix $A$ ,  $A^t  A \neq A A^t $

$A^t$ means the transpose of $A$.

That is the entire question and I have no idea how to begin... please help!

Comment: Have you tried arbitrary small (e.g. $2\times 2$) matrices?

Comment: Try writing down a matrix $A$ and testing it out. You're trying to exhibit a *counterexample*, so it just comes down to finding a matrix $A$ that breaks the claimed identity.

Comment: If $A$ is not a square matrix, $A^TA$ and $AA^T$ aren’t even the same size.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $e_{12}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$. In general any counterexample to a matrix problem that *works* in dimension $2$ works in higher dimensions by extending a matrix appropriately, so look at the $2$ dimensional case first! Note that $e_{12}^t=e_{21}$ and that $e_{12}e_{21}=e_{11}$ while $e_{21}e_{12}=e_{22}$. In general it is not a bad idea to look at the elementary matrices $e_{ij}=(\delta_{ij})$, since they have simple rules for computation, like

$$e_{ij}e_{kl}=\delta_{jk}e_{il}\\ e_{ij}^t=e_{ji}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$A = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & a \\
     b & 1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Now,

$$A\cdot A^T = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & a \\
     b & 1
  \end{array} \right]
\cdot
\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & b \\
     a & 1
  \end{array} \right]
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1+a^2 & a+b \\
     a+b & b^2+1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Whereas

$$
A^T \cdot A = \left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & b \\
     a & 1
  \end{array} \right]
\cdot
\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1 & a\\
     b & 1
  \end{array} \right]
=
\left[
  \begin{array}{ c c }
     1+b^2 & a+b \\
     a+b & a^2+1
  \end{array} \right]
$$

Thus, $A^T \cdot A \neq A\cdot A^T$ in general.

Comment: Please check your TeX code.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff fixed